# How do I make a Raspberry PI, EMP & Solar Flare Proof?

Tags: raspberry-pi, faraday-cage

Is it possible to make a solar flare, or EMP proof Raspberry PI, that can still be protected while operational?

Comment: Are you not on earth? Solar flares are typically not a problem to non-radio-receiver hardware here.

Comment: I'll be honest, this question doesn't make much sense to me; what you're describing would be a system designed for resilience, with the ability to recover errors itself and so on. The raspberry pi is a device based on a cheap-as-possible TV set top box chip, for which failure absolutely *is* an option. Something is not quite right here! What is your use case? I think we can help you achieve your goal, but I'm really not convinced a raspberry pi will be part of the solution.

Comment: Take a look at mil qualed devices, however I do not believe the Pi is on that list.

Answer (score 2):

EMP should be no problem if you enclose the device in a Faraday cage, but of course be mindful of conducted interference if you have any wires going into or out of the cage.  Solar flares are a different matter, if you are planning to put a Pi into space then you’ll need to contend with all kinds of exotic radiation such as neutrons and x-rays that require rather different screening methods.

Comment: I wouldn't really call this "no problem". EMP-Proof cabling is _difficult_. You need completely shielded cables or special EMP plugs (Google eg. for "ethernet emp filter"). Doesn't look like these devices are in any way cheap...

Comment: Agreed, if the device is entirely self-contained then the job will be much easier than if it’s not.

Comment: True, but what would an "entirely self contained" device do? You would want to get some data in or out, or have some buttons or a display in the cage.

Comment: @PMF the high-power motor controller design experts I've talked to use fiberoptics to get the data and control from switching frontend to FPGA-implemented controller